# SQL: Trigger is not performing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a trigger to set the value of a column of the data type time to null when the time inserted is Less than GETDATE()

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[NULL_TIME_TRIGGER]
  on [dbo].[Products]
  after insert
  as
  update Products
  set ParkingStartTime = NULL
  from Products
   join inserted i
     on i.ParkingStartTime  = Products.ParkingStartTime 
  where i.ParkingStartTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME);
```

The problem is that when `I select * From table` the record is still having the time rather than being `NULL`.

Any Ideas ?

Regards.

Comment: You had mentioned in the other question that 'ParkingStartTime' was a time field as well - is that not the case?

Comment: Are you sure that your condition is `true`?. I mean, is `ParkingStartTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)`?

Comment: Instead of using the parkingstarttime, can you use the PK field of the Products table instead? (I'm thinking there is something not lining up there). Also, what if you have many lineitems that have the same parkingstarttime?

Comment: Why is the application sending in a start time, if you want it to be null is the first question.

Comment: @gregory: true, but joining just on the time is errorneous. If the field is 'time', then you can update multiple rows with his trigger, and I'm sure that is not intended. Is the IDENTITY field not available in inserted?

Comment: @M.R. that case was solved by using CAST `GETDATE()`

Comment: @Lamak It should be because the idea is whenever the reserved parking time has passed the System Time, the parking should be available again

Comment: @M.R. Is there a different approach to use if I had multiple records having the same time?

Comment: @Humam - I gotcha. So it 'is' intended, in the sense that if the time has passed, its available (null) again. Can you produce some sample data? Possibly one of your joins is not lining up..

Comment: @humam: no, this will affect multiple records if the time matches... for example, if you insert a row that is 5PM, and the time now is 6pm, and there are other rows that is in the DB that is 5pm, you will update both the rows...

Comment: @Humam Shbib - I do not know your application, however, on the surface, this is not the best approach. Instead of forcefully trying to null out past parking values, you should simply leave them there and evaluate "current" parking values by accounting for `ParkingStartTime >= Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP As Time)`.

Comment: @M.R. yes this is the idea of the application

Comment: @Humam - so based on what you are looking for, I think you have it more or less - if u can produce some sample data, it would make more sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsenna has one option, and it is superior in many respects. Here is how I would play your AFTER INSERT version (asssume int as PK):

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[NULL_TIME_TRIGGER]       
ON [dbo].[Products]       
AFTER INSERT       
AS

DECLARE @ID int

SELECT @ID = ID FROM INSERTED

UPDATE Products
SET ParkingStartTime = NULL
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Comment: This is basically a wrong approach to working with 'magic' tables in a trigger, because you are doing it as if `inserted` is going to always contain only one row, whereas it's possible to insert more than one, like in `INSERT...SELECT`. The OP has got it right, and you could simply apply your idea of joining on ID to the original trigger. (Besides you aren't checking the time column at all!)

Answer (score 1):

I think in end, you need a sql job, that just looks through and sets the time to null when there time criteria is less than getDate()

Comment: Agree. It can also be done at the time of consuming rows. I mean, some part of the application must use the time column for something. So when it's time to check/use the data again, calling the cleanup can be performed as part of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely don't know whats wrong with your trigger, it should be working AFAIK.

But this is definitely **not** the way to go. You *seem* to be trying to validate some inserted values. If that's the case, you should be using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT`, like you're currently doing.

So it would be like this:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[NULL_TIME_TRIGGER]
  on [dbo].[Products]
  instead of insert
  as
  begin
      insert into Products (
          field1, field2, ..., fieldn, ParkingStartTime
      ) select
          field1, field2, ..., fieldn,
          case when ParkingStartTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) then NULL else ParkingStartTime end
      from
          inserted
  end
  go
```

That way SQL Server will intercept all inserts into the `Products` table, and will only execute the insert inside the trigger, which fixes the `ParkingStartTime` value. So the trigger doesn't need to execute another update to make them right.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Let me make it clearer, basically the user is reserving a parking at a particular time. The time should be added to the corresponding database column as soon as the time added is less than the `GETDATE()` then it shoud reset the record to `NULL` to realease that parking lot and make it available again

Comment: @Humam Shbib: So you're saying that `ParkingStartTime` should be set to `NULL` **when** it is equal to the current time? If that's the case, this should not be implemented as an `INSERT` trigger. The "event" you are worried about is not an insertion at all; it is a moment at time.

Comment: @Humam Shbib: I'll try to make it clearer - I *guess* you should create a job/service. It will take all records from time to time, and set `ParkingStartTime` to `NULL` when it is greater or equal to the current time.

Comment: the operator is `<` because when `ParkingStarttime` is less than `GETDATE()` it should be reset to `null` so it is available

Comment: @Humam Shbib: OK, I suppose you're right. But the main point is that I don't think the trigger approach is feasible here. As far as I understand, that field will *not* be set to `NULL` during the insert - it'll be set to `NULL` only **after** some time has passed... So the main problem here is that the trigger approach is wrong (regardless of the comparison operator being used).

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, yes. When the row is inserted, the time value is greater than the current time so it's left untouched. When you are checking the contents of the table, some values are already past the current time at the moment of checking.

Comment: yup - I was thinking along the same lines, which is why I had asked to see the data :)